# Is implementation of MultiLineComment wrong?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Quote from ECMAScript:

```
MultiLineComment ::
/* MultiLineCommentCharsopt */

MultiLineCommentChars ::
MultiLineNotAsteriskChar MultiLineCommentCharsopt
* PostAsteriskCommentCharsopt

PostAsteriskCommentChars ::
MultiLineNotForwardSlashOrAsteriskChar MultiLineCommentCharsopt
* PostAsteriskCommentCharsopt

MultiLineNotAsteriskChar ::
SourceCharacter but not *

MultiLineNotForwardSlashOrAsteriskChar ::
SourceCharacter but not one of / or *
```

If I understand correctly, then records like `/***/` or `/*/*/` should cause an error, but this does not happen. Why it happens?

P.S I checked this in google chrome, firefox, opera and maxthone

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @SalmanA Where am I wrong?

Comment: nope - the implementation is correct.. `/***/` reders to `/*`*`/*` - commenting the star out as expected - there's no space needed after.. `/*`

Comment: @MaximPro Please explain why you think they should cause an error

Comment: @Bergi `/* MultiLineCommentCharsopt */ :: * PostAsteriskCommentCharsopt :: MultiLineNotForwardSlashOrAsteriskChar :: MultiLineNotForwardSlashOrAsteriskChar :: SourceCharacter but not one of / or *` for `/***/`

Comment: @MaximPro So yes, the `MultilineCommenChars` consist only of a single `*`, the optional `PostAsteriskCommentChars` are left off. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Bergi If I understand correctly, is `*` discarded? And the record `/***/` is perceived as `/**/`? Right?

Comment: @MaximPro Not sure what you mean by "discarded", or why that should cause an error. It's the content of the comment. Of course, both are ignored during evaluation of the code.

Comment: @Bergi Well what happens under this condition if we meet `*` `MultiLineNotForwardSlashOrAsteriskChar ::SourceCharacter but not one of / or *`

Comment: @MaximPro Sorry, I don't follow your notation. And what do you mean by "happens under condition" - those are grammar rules, nothing "happens" here.

Comment: @Bergi I understand, I want to understand how the rules will be read. Where inside the structure `/**/` will be `*`

Comment: If you parse `/**/` according to the `MultiLineComment` rule, then `/*` and `*/` are the literal parts and the *optional* `MultiLineCommentChars` doesn't occur at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/***/`:

The outer `/*` ... `*/` are the pattern for the MultilineComment, so the inner `*` has to match the MultilineCommentChars. Now if you look at that you see that:

```
MultiLineCommentChars ::
 * PostAsteriskCommentChars [opt]
```

actually can be just an `*` as the following part is optional (thats what the `[opt]` means).

`/*/*/`:

The outer is again the MultilineComment pattern, `/` has to match the MultilineCommentChars, which it does as

```
MultiLineCommentChars ::
 MultiLineNotAsteriskChar MultiLineCommentChars [opt]
```

and `/` is part of the MultilineNotAsteriskChar.

Now the whole section only is there to prevent a `*/` inside the MultilineComment, `/**/*/` is invalid, `/*/**/` isn't.

Comment: Exactly, I did not perceive `*` in `MultiLineCommentChars` as part of the nonterminal symbol.